# how to mock a location.path in angular unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, location, karma-runner

http://blog.artlogic.com/2013/05/06/angularjs-best-practices-ive-been-doing-it-wrong-part-2-of-3/

I am testing a routing directive with location.path refs to templates that cannot be found. So....

I want to mock a routing test with a mock configured $routeProvider, how to get the $routeProvider in karma/jasmine?

then I tried the spyOn mock approach described in best-practice, is there a syntax for which I can expect the $location.path().toBe('/path')?

```
spyOn($location, 'path').andCallFake(new LocationMock().path);
```

and I was wondering if I could

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eitanp461/6wMJ6/) which demonstrates mocking $location.

```
  app.controller('testcont', function($scope, $location) {
      $scope.path = $location.path();
  });
  ...
  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $location){    
     scope = $rootScope.$new();
     spyOn($location, 'path').andReturn('Fake location');
     $controller('testcont', {$scope:scope});
  }));
  ...
  it('should spy on $location', function($location){
     expect(scope.path).toBe('Fake location');
  });
```

However templates can be loaded by prepopulating Angular's $templateCache with the directive.
Karma uses the [ng-html2js-preprocessor](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor). Could that help your problem?

Comment: well the key is that I need to reroute $routeProvider.when.... in a routing test.