# Angularjs: mock location.path() with spyOn for a unit test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, spyon

I have already read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642162/how-to-mock-a-location-path-in-angular-unit-tests) (and others) but I don't manage to make this simple unit test work. I'm using the version 2 of Jasmine. 
My factory is very simple:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('detectPath', function ($location, $rootScope) {
        'use strict';
        var locationPath = $location.path()
        function getPath () {
            if (locationPath === '/') {
                locationPath = 'home';
            } else {
                locationPath = '';
            }
            $rootScope.path = locationPath;
        }
        getPath();
        return locationPath;
    });
```

And my unit test is just as simple:

```
'use strict';
describe('Factory: detectPath', function () {
    var detectPath, $rootScope, $location;

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));
    beforeEach(inject(function (_detectPath_, _$rootScope_, _$location_) {
        detectPath = _detectPath_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $location = _$location_;
        spyOn($location, 'path').and.returnValue('/');
    }));

    it('should return pathName', function ($location) {
        expect($rootScope.path).toBe('home');
    });
});
```

This doesn't pass the test (I get the error expect false to be "home").

What I am doing wrong?
Is there a way to verify that spyOn has been called (only once)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two main problems with your code.

First of all, your `getPath()` function is executed before you are setting spy. You should either set the spy in the previous `beforeEach` or inject your factory in the test (I went for the second solution).

The second problem (which does not influence the test yet) is that you hide your `$location` variable with test's function argument - you will not be able to access it as it will always be undefined. After I removed this arg, I'm able to test if spy has been called with [`expect(...).toHaveBeenCalled()`](http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/introduction.html).

Here is a working code:

```
describe('Factory: detectPath', function () {
    var detectPath, $rootScope, $location;

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));
    beforeEach(inject(function (_$rootScope_, _$location_) {
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $location = _$location_;
        spyOn($location, 'path').and.returnValue('/');
    }));

    it('should return pathName', function () {
        inject(function (detectPath) {
            expect($location.path).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect($rootScope.path).toBe('home');
        });
    });
});
```

And [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fracz/b7BRR/28/) (using Jasmine 1.3 but the only difference in this sample is that you call `and.returnValue` in Jasmine 2 and `returnValue` in Jasmine 1.3).